# Normalizer of UNIPOTENT Group in the General Linear Group

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I know that this question has been asked already. But I am unable to understand the solution and hence I am trying another way.

I am interested in computing the normalizer of Upper Triangular Matrices with diagonal entries $1$ in $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$. Denote the subgroup of upper triangular matrices with diagonal matrices $1$ by $\mathbb{U}$

So I want to compute the following $\{M \in GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p) : M\mathbb{U}
      M^{-1} \in \mathbb{U}\}$

So I am looking for elements $M$ such that $M(1+N_1)=(1+N_2)M$ where $N_i$ are the strictly upper triangular matrices.

Thus we have $MU_1M^{-1}=U_2$. The restriction is that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are strictly upper triangular matrices.

I wonder if I can conclude that M must be an upper triangular matrix from here? Because upper triangular matrices are closed under multiplication and since eigenvalues of $U_1$ are $0$, then $U_2$ is upper triangular and since eigenvalues are $0$ which follows by matrix simmilarity, it is strictly upper triangular

I am sure that the answer will be the set of upper triangular matrices as they satisfy the condition $MU_1M^{-1}=U_2$. Any solutions following this way is appreciated.

Comment: Please link to the previous question, and explain **exactly** what you are unable to understand about the solution. Otherwise, this is also going to get closed, just like your previous question on the exact same matter was closed earlier today.

Comment: Moreover, this is **identical** to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3950126/normalizer-of-upper-triangular-matrices-with-diagonal-entries-1-in-gl-n-mathbb) with just an added paragraph. You should not post a brand new question in that situation: you should edit your old question, and then request that it be re-opened in meta, making a case for the reopening. This needs to be removed.

Comment: @arturo, The extra paragraph you are talking about is my attempt for this problem. Why am I supposed to learn a way you want? Is it because people here are too lazy to learn/discuss? As far as I remember MSQ guidelines states that " one is supposed to post their attempt for the question, so that others can guide you from there". Then why you aren't helping me from the attempt that I have already made?

Comment: @arturo. For the last question ,MSQ shows that we are supposed to ask a new question if you think that the your post is not a duplicate. Then why can't I ask a new question when MSQ suggested me that?

Comment: You are not supposed to post an identical question with an added paragraph: you are supposed to *edit* your previous question to add the paragraph, and then request a re-open. I do not require you to do it one way, but your post suggests that the *only* reason you aren’t doing it that way is your lack of understanding. If you have other reasons, then the proper way to use this site is to link to that question and **explain** why that is no good, or why you want another way. Why should I help someone who can’t be bothered to use this site the way it’s supposed to be used?

Comment: If you want to discuss laziness, let’s discuss your laziness: did you read the FAQ? Did you find out what you are supposed to do when you post a question, it is closed, and you disagree with that closure? Or did you just decide to do as you wish, because why should you bother? Are you too lazy to learn/discuss?  Or do you think the best way to get people to help you for free is to insult them?

Comment: It's legitimate to psot your attempt at a solution and to ask for verification of its correctness. But what you have written here cannot be described as an attempt at a solution, because you haven't really made any significant progress. I have just noticed that I posted the solution for the linked post, so please feel free to ask for clarification of anything you don't understand.